# Push and Pop behaviour is strange, why?

Tags: iphone, stack, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I have two classes, the one is addAlarm and second is Name,,,

for now I am in addAlarm (addAlarm is subclass of UITableViewController), as it selects the row, then it goes to Name class as below

```
        Name *ob = [[Name alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ob animated:YES];

        [ob release];
        ob = nil;
```

then there is UINavigationBar with addAlarm as back button by default, while Name is also subclass of UITableViewController

I observe that when I click addAlarm backbutton in Name, then it goes back to addAlarm, and its viewWillAppear Method calls, but after that it calls

```
         - (void)viewDidUnload
```

and

```
         - (void)dealloc
```

of Name Class.

I am unable to understand that why it is calling the methods of Name after it executes ViewWillApear of addAlarm, any Idea?

Comment: this is expected behavior. If you click on back button it should call viewDidUnload and dealloc method of class which you are leaving from. This is not the problem.

Comment: but Deeps, how can I save data to delegate method and show in other class, while it is not calling its method before the next class?

Comment: It this question get solved, then problem will be solved, cz in ViewWillApear, I am calling [self.tableView reloadData] and it is now taking updated data because data updates in dealloc method of name, what should I do ?

Comment: you should not update data in dealloc !!! Only release objects there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing data in dealloc method You can Pass data in below method.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

}
```

Another Method is to store it in appDelegate file like below.

In appDelegate.h file

```
NSString *strName;
```

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strName;

In appDelegate.m file

```
@synthesize strName;
```

Now, you can create object of Application in your NameController like below

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

And store value like this

```
appDelegate.strName = @"Value to be passed to addAlarm View"
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Deeps, I have solved my problem, but can you tell me that Name object will release automatically, or not?

Comment: Great you solved. You can write [strName release] in dealloc method of appDelegate.h file.

Comment: then this delegate will be called at last of the app when app going to be closed, upto that will it be in memory?

Comment: Yes it is. You can release it and make it nil whenever you don't want it anymore.