# how to Pass values between views in popViewControllerAnimated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cell, tableview

I want to know how to pass values  between views in popViewControllerAnimated .

Here is my scenario:
I have a view which contains tableview on selecting the cell we go to another view where i need to enter value in textbox and i click a button to go back to the previous view where i need to display the textbox value in the table view cell.

How can i do this ?

This what i have done:

```
NewContact *nc = [[NewContact alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewContact" bundle:nil];
// ...
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
nc.name=[firstName text];
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:nc animated:YES];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[nc release];
```

Comment: The most professional way (might be overdone but will be very helpful when scaling the App): create a proper data model and allow your viewcontrollers to access the model objects directly.

Comment: Refer to the existing `NewContact` instance using the `parentViewController` property of `UIViewController`.

Comment: Hi deepak can you explain please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass value to parent controller when dismiss the controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606355/pass-value-to-parent-controller-when-dismiss-the-controller)

Comment: @user746909 Look at a very similar question I have marked as duplicate. It should explain various approaches to solving this including my own.

Comment: Hi deepak , i want to call parent class method using popViewControllerAnimated

Comment: Do you mean you want to call a method in the `parentViewController` before you do `popViewControllerAnimated:`?

Comment: Yeah @Deepak actually he need opposite stuff than the link you provided.

Comment: yeah,i need to call parentViewController method.

Answer (score 4):

In ViewControllerB, declare delegate and set action for popViewControllerAnimated:

```
@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController {
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;

@synthesize delegate;

- (id) init ... {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(didBack:)] autorelease];
}

- (void) didBack:(id)sender {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(setProperty:)]) { 
        [delegate setProperty:property];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In ViewControllerA, provide a function to set the local property and set delegate:

```
ViewControllerB controllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init...];
[controllerB setDelegate:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerB animated:YES];
[controllerB release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store value in one of the global variable for example you can declare in appDelegate file. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717269/push-and-pop-behaviour-is-strange-why/6717355#6717355) for that

If you are using UITextField then you can store value in above variable from UITextField in below delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Are you sure this is what the OP wants?

Comment: @Deepak Yes as per his description. He wanted to store some value when poptoViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NSNotificationCenter` for this, passing an object along with the call.

Howto: [Send and receive messages through NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/how-to-send-and-receive-message-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement in your comment,

Say you navigate from `ViewControllerA` instance to `ViewControllerB` instance and you wish to call `ViewControllerA`'s methods, you can do it like this,

```
ViewControllerA * viewControllerA = (ViewControllerA *)self.parentViewController.
[viewController methodToCall];
```

To use this to address the requirement in the question, you can use a property.

```
viewControllerA.name = firstName.text; // Bits from your code snippet
```

However in a table view I would expect you to have a mutable array powering the data source. You can refer to it, assuming that it is an property.

```
[viewControllerA.dataSourceArray addObject:firstName.text];
```

Comment: Making use of the delegation pattern, one could **avoid coupling** `ViewControllerA`and `ViewControllerB`, but it is a little more elaborate.